# c# RenderInfo.GetText() does not return Line breaks in certain PDFs. How can I get them?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, line-breaks, decoding

### My goal

I am searching specific text in the PDF, sometimes it can include line breaks. In this example I want the 3-line text in the marked rectangle from the screenshot below:

[image]

### My code

I use the following c# code with iTextSharp 5.5.13.3

```
var fontStrategy = new GetFontsExtractionStrategy();
using (var reader = new PdfReader("C:\\pdf.pdf")
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, fontStrategy);
    }
}
Logging.LogInfo($"PDF text: {fontStrategy.lastChunks}");

public class GetFontsExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    public string lastChunks;

    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        var txt = renderInfo.GetText();
        lastChunks += txt;
    }
}
```

### The result

The text which inside the `lastChunks` is *(I just extracted the relevant text of the whole PDF text)*:

- `Unvani (T�zel Kisiler doldurulacaktir.) (Kisaltma yapilmadan Ticaret Sicilinde yer aldigi bi�imde yazilacaktir)`

The expected found text with line breaks would be

```
Unvani (T�zel Kisiler doldurulacaktir.)
(Kisaltma yapilmadan Ticaret Sicilinde yer
aldigi bi�imde yazilacaktir)
```

### My Question

How can I get the right text in this case? I am also open to changing the library if necessary. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: line break characters are _not_ part of the _text_ you retrieve via `RenderText`, they have to be deduced from further `TextRenderInfo` details, in particular its Baseline: You compare the base line of this info object with the base line of the previous info object. If there is a considerable vertical gap, add a line break character. As you derive your class from the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, you can let yourself be inspired by the way that class does so.

Comment: @mkl do you have any code snippet ready? Because I would imagine this is a common question and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well, take a look at the code of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` you based your code on - in its original Form it does add the appropriate newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public StringBuilder lastChunks = new StringBuilder();

public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    var txt = renderInfo.GetText();
    lastChunks.AppendLine(txt);
}
```

I hope to help you..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I add this code it will add a new line after each PDF chunk that's too much. In this PDF the chunks are 1-6 characters long so this is solution seems not reliable.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**